# More efficient way to fuzzy match in R?

Tags: r

I am currently working on a data frame with 2 million lines (records). I am wanting to identify potential duplicate records for followup. Someone else has written for me a long code that works, but currently it is taking me overnight to run.

It uses the `stringdist` package. From what I understand, `stringdist` works by comparing  one row, against all other rows in the data frame. So, a data frame with 5 rows would require 20 computations:

i.e. 
row 1 compared  to row 2
row 1 compared  to row 3
row 1 compared  to row 4
row 1 compared  to row 5
row 2 compared  to row 1
row 2 compared  to row 3
row 2 compared  to row 4
row 2 compared  to row 5
row 3 compared  to row 1
row 3 compared  to row 2
row 3 compared  to row 4
row 3 compared  to row 5
row 4 compared  to row 1
row 4 compared  to row 2
row 4 compared  to row 3
row 4 compared  to row 5
row 5 compared  to row 1
row 5 compared  to row 2
row 5 compared  to row 3
row 5 compared  to row 4

An increase in the size of data frame would exponentially increase the time needed to complete the function. With my rather large data frame, obviously it takes a while.

My proposed solution is this: after  comparing  each row with all of the other rows in the data frame, is there a way to omit those rows from future computations? For example, in the example above, row 1 compared  to row 2 would be the same as row 2 compared to row 1. Could we remove one of these calculations?

So, using the example data frame above, the only computations should be:

row 1 compared  to row 2
row 1 compared  to row 3
row 1 compared  to row 4
row 1 compared  to row 5
row 2 compared  to row 3
row 2 compared  to row 4
row 2 compared  to row 5
row 3 compared  to row 4
row 3 compared  to row 5
row 4 compared  to row 5

This is the section in a function in the code that looks for these duplicates in various columns - any ideas on how I can amend this?

```r
lastName <- stringdist(DataND$SURNAME[rownumber],DataND$SURNAME, method='lv')
firstName <- stringdist(DataND$GIVEN.NAME[rownumber],DataND$GIVEN.NAME, method='lv')
birthDate <- stringdist(DataND$DOB[rownumber],DataND$DOB, method='lv')
streetAddress<-stringdist(DataND$ADDR.1[rownumber],DataND$ADDR.1, method='lv')
suburb <- stringdist(DataND$LOCALITY[rownumber],DataND$LOCALITY, method='lv')
```

Comment: `combn` will give you all the unique comparisons, `m` at a time. e.g.: `combn(1:5, m=2)` - would that be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

H 1's idea is great. Another option would be the `fuzzyjoin`-package.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(id = seq(1,10),
             words = replicate(10, paste(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = "")))



stringdist_left_join(df, df, by = c(words = "words"), max_dist = 5, method = "lv", distance_col = "distance") %>%
  filter(distance != 0)

# A tibble: 90 x 5
    id.x words.x  id.y words.y distance
   <int> <chr>   <int> <chr>      <dbl>
 1     1 JUQYR       2 HQMFD          5
 2     1 JUQYR       3 WHQOM          4
 3     1 JUQYR       4 OUWJV          4
 4     1 JUQYR       5 JURGD          3
 5     1 JUQYR       6 ZMLAQ          5
 6     1 JUQYR       7 RWLVU          5
 7     1 JUQYR       8 AYNLE          5
 8     1 JUQYR       9 AUPVJ          4
 9     1 JUQYR      10 JDFEY          4
10     2 HQMFD       1 JUQYR          5
# ... with 80 more rows
```

Here you have it all set up in the end, you can pick and dismiss rows by distance. It took 11 seconds for 100.000 records. Trying with `stringdistmatrix()` however I got the error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 37.3 Gb

Answer (score 0):

`lastName<-stringdist(DataND$SURNAME[rownumber], DataND$SURNAME, method='lv')`

If i understand this line, it compar one surname (according the value of rownumber) with aller surnames. So when you change `rownumber`, all comparisons are made, even the ones already done precedently.

To prevent this, try:

`lastName<-stringdist(DataND$SURNAME[rownumber], DataND$SURNAME[rownumber:nrows], method='lv')`
where `nrows` is the number of rows